# npm start showing error The attribute aria-invalid is not supported by the role radio. This role is implicit on the element input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wai-aria

I am facing below error for npm start
**src/components/Common/Radio/index.js
19:7  error  The attribute aria-invalid is not supported by the role radio. This role is implicit on the element input  jsx-a11y/role-supports-aria-props**

code for Radio/index.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import parse from 'html-react-parser';
    
    const Radio = (props) => {
      const {
        id,
        value,
        checked,
        handleChange,
        text,
        name,
        invalid,
        children,
        disabled
      } = props;
      return (
        <div className="form-item form-type-radio">
          <input
            type="radio"
            id={id}
            className="form-checkbox"
            value={value}
            checked={checked}
            disabled={disabled || undefined}
            name={name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            aria-invalid={!!invalid} />
          <label className={`option ${invalid}`} htmlFor={id}>
            {text ? parse(text) : null}
            {children}
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    Radio.propTypes = {
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      value: PropTypes.string,
      text: PropTypes.string,
      checked: PropTypes.bool,
      name: PropTypes.string,
      handleChange: PropTypes.func,
      invalid: PropTypes.string,
      disabled: PropTypes.bool
    };
    
    export default Radio;
```

Please provide your help to fix the error.
Could you please provide the acceptable aria attributes for radio button.

Answer (score 0):

aria-invalid can also be used to indicate that a required field has not been filled in